# Metamask sees contract address as personal address

Tags: metamask

While using MetaMask I inadvertently transferred an NFT from a wallet address to the NFT's contract address. I am using my own network (Ganache-cli) for development. The transaction went through. The problem is that now MetaMask (iOS app) interprets the NFT contract address as a personal address. So when I try to add an NFT from that contract, it throws the error:

> "Personal address detected. Input the collectible contract address".

I reset all the accounts on the device, but that didn't help. I am certain that the contract address is correct.

I there anyway to fix this, or will I need to reset the chain (Ganache)?

Comment: Did you uninstall and reinstalled metamask?

Comment: Yes, I tried reinstalling but it did not help.

Comment: I stopped Ganache and restarted it using the mnemonic phrase, it seems to have preserved the wallet addresses and balances but not the contract address and I think that is likely the problem. Regardless, I messed something up along the way, so I have no choice but restart with a fresh chain.